# JS queryCommandState("superscript") always return false

Tags: javascript, wysiwyg, contenteditable

```
document.queryCommandState("superscript"); //always return false
document.queryCommandState("bold"); // works fine
```

how to detect sub or sup in contentEditable element?

Comment: Works fine for me in Chrome and Firefox: http://jsfiddle.net/eabf3bnv/

Comment: Dosen't work with hiliteColor command either on firefox or chrome

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm rather late to this, but just for documentation purpose I thought I would reply to it:

This has most likely to do with the styling of the `<sub />`/`<sup />` element.
In the example by @tim-down the default style is being used. I updated the fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/alarie/vzxh3818/) to use some styles and then `queryCommandState` will return `false`. (In this case it's actually the `vertical-align: baseline;` property that breaks it)

The spec actually contains this note about how the state is to be determined from the **effective command value**:

> NOTE [effective command value] is logically somewhat like CSS computed or resolved values,
>   and in fact for most commands it's identical to CSS resolved values
>   (see the end of the algorithm). We need a separate concept for some
>   commands where we can't rely on CSS for some reason: createLink and
>   unlink aren't CSS-related at all, backColor and hiliteColor need
>   special treatment because background-color isn't an inherited
>   property, subscript and superscript rely on `<sub>`/`<sup>` instead of CSS
>   vertical-align, and strikethrough and underline don't map to unique
>   CSS properties.
>
> Source: https://w3c.github.io/editing/execCommand.html#assorted-inline-formatting-command-algorithms

And here is the actual algorithm for superscript/subscript (from that same spec):

> 1. Let affected by subscript
>      and affected by superscript be two boolean variables, both initially
>      false.
> 2. While node is an inline node:
>
>    > NOTE Firefox 6.0a2 ignores
>    >     vertical-align for this purpose, and only cares about  and 
>    >     tags themselves. Opera 11.11 is similar, and in fact behaves like that
>    >     even for commands like bold. The spec originally followed Chrome 14
>    >     dev, mainly because WebKit itself will produce spans with
>    >     vertical-align sub or super, and we want to handle them correctly.
>    >     However, Ryosuke informs me that WebKit's behavior here is viewed as a
>    >     bug, so I changed it to match Gecko/Opera.
>
>    **If node is a sub, set affected by subscript to true.** <- this is where chrome/webkit behaves incorrectly
> 3. Otherwise, if node is a sup, set affected by superscript to true. Set
>      node to its parent. If affected by subscript and affected by
>      superscript are both true, return the string "mixed". If affected by
>      subscript is true, return "subscript". If affected by superscript is
>      true, return "superscript". Return null.

So the solution as of now would be 1) don't fiddle with the style, or rather 2) make the check yourself.

Comment: Awesome answer. How do you check yourself ? Any idea ?